# Creating a unique constraint for 2 columns 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a unique constraint based on two columns.

How do I achieve that in SQL Server 2008 Express edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT YourConstraintName UNIQUE (Column1, Column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (
  Col1,
  Col2
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

or if you prefer with an index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX myindex ON mytable (
  Col1,
  Col2
) ON [PRIMARY]
```